# How does the aspect ratio media query work?

Tags: css, media

I'm having a bit of trouble finding info on this subject. It seems min and max is used with it and I'm confused because min or max implies a change and if a part of the ratio is changed it wouldnt be a ratio. Could some explain this and clear up this confusion, also is this something that isnt used by many considering the lack of resources for it, are other things better to use?

```
@media screen and (aspect-ratio: 16/9){
         background-color: blue;
}
```

Comment: Think of `min-aspect-ratio: 16/9` as anything wider than 16/9, that is, 17:9, 18:9, etc. Just specifying `aspect-ratio` as in your example will target that specific ratio only, i.e. the browser happens to be resized precisely at that ratio.

I can hardly think of a common use-case for just `aspect-ratio`. Prefixed with `min-` and `max-` it can probably be used determine, well, the approximate aspect-ratio or the "orientation" of the viewport to make design decisions based on it.

Answer (score 0):

you got no selector – it would have to be

```
@media screen and (aspect-ratio: 16/9){

   body{
         background-color: blue;
   }

}
```